# List last 5 records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, date

I am trying to list last 5 records untill current date(recent appointments).Here s my controller works well but how can I filter it just for 5 records and which are dated before today.

```
  using (var db = new MaindbModelDataContext())
            {
                var patient = db.Patients.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == (String)Session["UserEmail"]);
                var listrecent = from y in db.Appointments
                                 where y.PatientNo == patient.PatientNo
                                 select y;
                var TempRecent = new List<Models.AppModel>();
                foreach (var item in listrecent)
                {
                    var Temp = new Models.AppModel();
                    Temp.AppNo = item.AppNo;
                    Temp.PatientNo = (Int32)item.PatientNo;
                    Temp.Date = (DateTime)item.Date;
                    Temp.Status = item.Status;
                    Temp.Description = item.Description;
                    TempRecent.Add(Temp);

                }
                return View(TempRecent);
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("RegAndLogin", "User");
        }
    }

}
```

and here is my view

```
@model IEnumerable<DentAppSys.Models.AppModel>
@using System.Web.Helpers
 <section class="Patient-Dashboard">

        <div id="dashboard_left">
            <h1> Recent Appointments</h1>
   @{
    var Mygrid = new WebGrid(Model, selectionFieldName: "SelectedRow");
}

@Mygrid.GetHtml(
    displayHeader: true,
    alternatingRowStyle: "alt",
    selectedRowStyle: "select",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,

columns: Mygrid.Columns
(

    Mygrid.Column("Appointment No", "Appointment No",format: @<text>@item.AppNo</text>),
    Mygrid.Column("Patient No", "Patient No", format: @<text>@item.PatientNo</text>) ,
    Mygrid.Column("Description", "Description", format: @<text>@item.Description</text>),
    Mygrid.Column("Date", "Date", format: @<text>@item.Date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")</text>),
    Mygrid.Column("Status", "Status", format: @<text>@item.Status</text>)

))
</div>

<div id="dashboard_right">
<br/>
<h1>Incoming Appointments</h1>
</div>
</section>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could tag the question with the framework you're using? That way it's more likely someone can correctly answer the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe something like this in your linq statement should work:

```
var listrecent = (from y in db.Appointments
                 where y.PatientNo == patient.PatientNo
                 where y.Date < DateTime.Today
                 orderby y.Date descending
                 select y).Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks i will use it.I have another question I want to show to list .Recent Appointment(dated before today) and Incoming Appointments(dated after today).Which filter i should use?

Comment: You can use very similar logic, probably delete the 'descending' and the 'Take', then modify the 'where' statement.